# What is the R package's best practice to check arguments of functions that have not run yet?

Tags: r, arguments, r-package

#### Problem definition

In a package, users can choose different options and pass additional parameters based on those options. Since these functions are computationally challenging, I want to check whether the user passed the required argument or not before conducting any large scale runs. For example, in the following code:

```
FunOne <- function(x, y, z,...){
FunTwo(x,y,z, ...) # computationally challenging
FunThree(x,y,z, ...)
}
```

Inputs of `FunThree` is dependent on the `z` argument. If `z="option 1"`, argument `arg1 = 100` should be passed. If `z = "option 2"`,  `arg2 = "value"`, should be passed.

#### Possible solution

I know the required arguments for each option. I want to load them as a global variable and then double-check to see if they are passed or not (e.g., `pkg.env <- new.env(parent = emptyenv()`). I can do this in a separate function and run that function at the beginning of the analysis.

#### My qustions

1. Is this a good practice to double-check arguments in the R package?
2. How can I run a function in the background upon loading the package. Please give me a package side solution, not the user side solution (e.g., ~/.Rprofile). I want this to happen without users' intervention.

Comment: maybe split this in multiple functions, for example aproach 1 gets its own function then just use match.arg() or rlang arg_match for choice based arguments and use a simple if checks and stuff

Comment: Thanks @Bruno , I think I cannot do that. I want to test the function before running it because many parameters are additional parameters, and it is possible to miss one or two required parameters (based on other options.) As a result, I need to check them before starting any significant computation.

Comment: It's not good practice to have global variables. It's good practice to assert correct input with stopifnot().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are suggesting could work.  I don't fully understand the value/purpose of the global variables, and generally try to avoid such things.  But strictly speaking it will work.  Seems like there are two things missing:

1. `list(...)` will put the `...` values in a list so you can examine them.  See the help for `...`.
2. `.onAttach` will run when the package loads.  Here is an example:

```
.onAttach <- function(...) {

  # Do something when the package loads

}
```

Also note that you don't even need the .onAttach for populating environment variables.  You can just do it at the top of your code file.